# Last time I did something that I am doing now

Tags: meaning-in-context

So I live in Switzerland, and I am on my way to Austria. 
During a conversation on the train (having crossed the Swiss border), I mentioned that the last time I left Switzerland was in May.

I received the feedback that: "**the last time** you left Switzerland is now or when we crossed the border."

Help me out. Which is correct and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You’re fine to use “last” to mean “previous”.

In conversational English, it’s well understood that when you say

> “the last time I left home”

This means

> “the time before this one.”

In highly technical contexts — for example, written instructions or a legal document — your friend is correct. “Last” can be used to mean “only the most recent time.”

But in everyday speaking, your meaning is understood.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. This is what i had in mind as well. Nevertheless i thought it would be better to get a third opinion as well.